# Are the speakers in a good position?

Tags: sound-design, microphone, speakers, recommendations

I use two 12 EV Live speaker [EV Link](https://www.electrovoice.com/product.php?id=1066)  in a 8 meter space to stage. Is this position is good for this room with height 3 meters and 50 people in this room?

[image: Position]

Comment: Can you please explain how you use your setup, what type of sound-reinforcment you need/want. Maybe a drawing of the room/stage/setup from a birds-eye view would be better than the photo. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have one speaker in a corner and one against a wall. Consequently the speaker in the corner will have an enhance bass response compared with the other speaker.
I would recommend placing the speakers symmetrically with respect to the wall positioning in the room. In a room this size, it would be better to keep the speakers against the wall as this will avoid any room modes.

Comment: what do u mean by " it would be better to keep the speakers against the wall as this will avoid any room modes."

Comment: http://www.acousticfrontiers.com/room-modes-101/